# lapply and readxl Error

Tags: r, import, lapply, readxl

I am using `readxl` and `lapply` to import multiple `.xlsx` files into my environment. The following worked perfectly before but now when I try to re-run it, it gives me the following error:

`Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet = sheet, limits = limits, shim = shim,  : 
 Evaluation error: zip file 'data.xlsx' cannot be opened.`

Code:

`setwd("./Data Folder")` #set path in order to avoid lapply error (This is what solved it last time I got errors)

#### Load all "Data Folder" datasets

`library(readxl)`

`file.list <- list.files(path = "./Data Folder", pattern = '*.xlsx')
 df.list   <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)`

I have checked if the path I entered is still correct and I didn't alter it by mistake. I have also tried to open the documents in the folder using excel and there is no problem with the files. Any ideas?

Comment: does `file.list` perhaps contain names of some files other than  `xlsx`? Maybe a safer pattern is `'*\\.xlsx$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. I had two different tabs opened in RStudio, one was a `R markdown` and the other an `R Script`. I was trying to run the code in `R markdown` without realising and so I got the `lapply` error as the `setwd` was not saved in R's system.

If anyone has this problem at any point:

- check if you are in an `R Script`
- set the folder you are taking the data out from as your home folder
- run the entire chunk in `markdown` at once